# codeigniter working fine on local xampp but 404 on apache web server for all custom controller

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have CodeIgniter(CI) Integration with Wordpress(WP). After many weeks of hard work finally integration is working in my local XAMP.

When I moved the same structure to server/production environment the integration between CI and WP still looks ok (I say it because CI's default controller works /welcome/index.php), but when I use any other custom controllers I only get 404.

I tries many options based on my google search effort such as 1.tweaking .htaccess 2. changes to config file 3. changes to route file and none of the solution working for me. I am hoping that someone might have a solution for this. Thank for reading and below are details.

Site structure:

```
Site Root
- All WP files
- .htaccess
- CI folder - contains all CI files
-- .htaccess
```

WP .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

CI .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

CI config file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mysitecom/ci/';
```

Local URLs:

```
http://localhost/ci/ --> works and gives me default Welcome index page
http://localhost/ci/book/ --> works and gives me right page
```

Apache Server URLs:

```
http://mysitecom/ci/ --> works and gives me default Welcome index page
http://mysitecom/ci/book/ --> Does NOT work and gives me 404 error
```

For the heck of it, I tried the following to see if I can force 'book' as default and it still gave me 404 for http://mysitecom/ci/**book**/

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'book';
```

Not sure why default CI controller works, but not custom controllers in apache web server. I may be missing something, but not sure what?

Comment: Did you make sure your controller have first letter only upper case on filename and class.

Comment: Great pointer and that was certainly an issue. I used upper case now for for class and file name for both controller and model classes. That solution resolved my 404, but now I am getting blank screen with no errors at all; checked all log files and no hints at all other than ' Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.'

Answer (score 1):

What I noticed is, you have miss match in config and .htaccess

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mysitecom/ci/';
```

In .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
```

This refers to root of the website that is http://mysitecom/

But your actual application is running on http://mysitecom/ci/

So

Replace it with

```
RewriteBase /ci/
```

Another area is file name, please make sure all controllers name start with caps.

For example if my controller is `Admin` then the file name should be `Admin.php` and you have to declare like

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller{
   --Code here---
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the guideline at https://www.cometchat.com/blog/how-to-integrate-codeigniter-with-wordpress/ to integrate codeigniter with wordpress? The point 1 (Add the WordPress Bootstrap File) is the most important.

In my case, my routes.php file looks like this:

```
$route['(?i)bookings/(:any)'] = 'bookings/$1'; 
$route['(?i)bookings'] = 'bookings';
$route['(?i)(:any)'] = 'bookings/index/$1';  
$route['default_controller'] = 'bookings/index';
```

Bookings is a controller, who is responsible of my booking system. It's in production at https://eventsol.es/transfers/